# How to not subscribe if values are equal to the last emission

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

###### Problem

How to not subscribe if values are equal to the last emission

```js
this.first$.next('one');
this.second$.next(false);
    
combine$ = combineLatest([this.first$, this.second$])
  .pipe(map(([first, second]) => {
    //do something if one of the values is different
  }))
```

Only subscribe if one of the values is different than the previous emitted values

###### Example

If:

- first emission:
  this.first$.next('one'); 
  this.second$.next(false); -> subscribe first values
- second emission: 
  this.first$.next('one'); 
  this.second$.next(false); -> do not subscribe second values

If:

- first emission:
  this.first$.next('one'); 
  this.second$.next(true);  -> subscribe first values
- second emission: 
  this.first$.next('one');  
  this.second$.next(false); -> subscribe second values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`distinctuntilchanged`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged) operator:

```js
const first$ = new Subject();
const second$ = new Subject();

const combined$ = combineLatest([first$, second$]).pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(
    (prev, curr) => prev[0] === curr[0] && prev[1] === curr[1]
  )
);
combined$.subscribe(([first, second]) => {
  console.log(first, second);
});

first$.next('One');
second$.next(true);

first$.next('One');
second$.next(true);
second$.next(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `distinctUntilChanged` operator to achieve the behavior you're looking for. This operator emits values from the source observable only if they are different from the previously emitted value. Here's how you can use the `distinctUntilChanged` operator in your code:

```js
combine$ = combineLatest([this.first$, this.second$])
  .pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged((prevValues, newValues) => {
      // Compare previous values with new values
      return (
        prevValues[0] === newValues[0] &&
        prevValues[1] === newValues[1]
      );
    }),
    map(([first, second]) => {
      // Do something with the values
    })
  );
```

In this code, the `distinctUntilChanged` operator is used to filter out consecutive emitted values that are the same as the previous emission. You provide a custom comparison function that takes the previous and new values as arguments and returns `true` if they are the same and should be ignored, or `false` if they are different and should be processed.

The `map` operator after `distinctUntilChanged` is where you can put your logic that operates on values that have passed the distinct check. This way, you achieve your goal of processing values only when they are different from the previous emissions.

Comment: Your first `map` operator does not make any sense., since you return it exactly the same, as it already is before your `map`.

Comment: @SvenMärki you are right. i removed the redundant code